# StackingCVRegressor feature_name mismatch error

Tags: python, pandas, algorithm, machine-learning

I'm trying to use StackingCV Regressor to increase the accuracy of my model. Model:

```
stack_gen = StackingCVRegressor(regressors = (xgb, gb, lin_reg, ridge, lasso),
                               meta_regressor = xgb,
                               use_features_in_secondary = True)
```

I'm able to fit the model using

```
stack_gen.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

However when I go to predict:

```
stack_gen.predict(X_test)
```

I get the error feature_names mismatch. Both the testing and training dataframes are the same size. They only differ by the amount of rows they have and I have previously fitted ML algorithms before with no issue. This only occurs when I attempt to stack. Confused on what the issue is with my code.

Error:

```
ValueError: feature_names mismatch: ['f0', 'f1', 'f2', 'f3', 'f4', 'f5', 'f6', 'f7', 'f8', 'f9', 'f10', 'f11', 'f12', 'f13', 'f14', 'f15', 'f16', 'f17', 'f18', 'f19', 'f20', 'f21', 'f22', 'f23', 'f24', 'f25', 'f26', 'f27', 'f28', 'f29', 'f30', 'f31', 'f32', 'f33', 'f34', 'f35', 'f36', 'f37', 'f38', 'f39', 'f40', 'f41', 'f42', 'f43', 'f44', 'f45', 'f46', 'f47', 'f48', 'f49', 'f50', 'f51', 'f52', 'f53', 'f54', 'f55', 'f56', 'f57', 'f58', 'f59', 'f60', 'f61', 'f62', 'f63', 'f64', 'f65', 'f66', 'f67', 'f68', 'f69', 'f70', 'f71', 'f72', 'f73', 'f74', 'f75', 'f76', 'f77', 'f78', 'f79', 'f80', 'f81', 'f82', 'f83', 'f84', 'f85', 'f86', 'f87', 'f88', 'f89', 'f90', 'f91', 'f92', 'f93', 'f94', 'f95', 'f96', 'f97', 'f98', 'f99', 'f100', 'f101', 'f102', 'f103', 'f104', 'f105', 'f106', 'f107', 'f108', 'f109', 'f110', 'f111', 'f112', 'f113', 'f114', 'f115', 'f116'] ['acousticness', 'danceability', 'duration_ms', 'energy', 'explicit', 'instrumentalness', 'liveness', 'loudness', 'speechiness', 'tempo', 'valence', 'year_1921', 'year_1922', 'year_1923', 'year_1924', 'year_1925', 'year_1926', 'year_1927', 'year_1928', 'year_1929', 'year_1930', 'year_1931', 'year_1932', 'year_1933', 'year_1934', 'year_1935', 'year_1936', 'year_1937', 'year_1938', 'year_1939', 'year_1940', 'year_1941', 'year_1942', 'year_1943', 'year_1944', 'year_1945', 'year_1946', 'year_1947', 'year_1948', 'year_1949', 'year_1950', 'year_1951', 'year_1952', 'year_1953', 'year_1954', 'year_1955', 'year_1956', 'year_1957', 'year_1958', 'year_1959', 'year_1960', 'year_1961', 'year_1962', 'year_1963', 'year_1964', 'year_1965', 'year_1966', 'year_1967', 'year_1968', 'year_1969', 'year_1970', 'year_1971', 'year_1972', 'year_1973', 'year_1974', 'year_1975', 'year_1976', 'year_1977', 'year_1978', 'year_1979', 'year_1980', 'year_1981', 'year_1982', 'year_1983', 'year_1984', 'year_1985', 'year_1986', 'year_1987', 'year_1988', 'year_1989', 'year_1990', 'year_1991', 'year_1992', 'year_1993', 'year_1994', 'year_1995', 'year_1996', 'year_1997', 'year_1998', 'year_1999', 'year_2000', 'year_2001', 'year_2002', 'year_2003', 'year_2004', 'year_2005', 'year_2006', 'year_2007', 'year_2008', 'year_2009', 'year_2010', 'year_2011', 'year_2012', 'year_2013', 'year_2014', 'year_2015', 'year_2016', 'year_2017', 'year_2018', 'year_2019', 'year_2020', 'class_average', 'class_highly popular', 'class_low interest', 'class_no interest', 'class_popular', 'class_top hit']
expected f91, f104, f98, f13, f93, f107, f5, f32, f17, f33, f40, f80, f20, f68, f54, f23, f56, f10, f1, f86, f84, f60, f66, f88, f28, f100, f14, f82, f36, f99, f26, f37, f70, f113, f69, f39, f22, f11, f78, f71, f3, f94, f92, f53, f106, f29, f24, f114, f87, f95, f62, f76, f111, f42, f72, f101, f105, f73, f35, f48, f109, f46, f43, f8, f85, f9, f30, f21, f59, f89, f90, f34, f15, f18, f25, f61, f64, f74, f112, f77, f44, f102, f19, f51, f2, f75, f81, f50, f41, f57, f52, f65, f79, f55, f47, f58, f12, f115, f31, f45, f67, f83, f97, f6, f38, f116, f108, f49, f103, f7, f110, f63, f16, f4, f0, f27, f96 in input data
training data did not have the following fields: year_1960, year_2020, year_1933, liveness, class_top hit, year_1992, year_1978, year_1938, year_1949, explicit, year_1952, year_2005, year_1972, year_1986, year_1940, year_2009, loudness, tempo, year_1947, year_2008, year_1975, year_1977, year_2012, year_1955, year_1979, speechiness, year_1939, year_2017, year_2018, year_1981, year_1942, year_1984, year_1968, instrumentalness, valence, year_2015, year_2016, year_2019, year_1948, year_1997, year_1995, year_1926, class_low interest, year_1925, year_2004, year_1998, year_1921, year_1945, year_2013, year_2014, class_average, year_1973, year_1946, year_1990, year_1924, year_1996, year_1993, year_2011, year_2006, year_1950, year_1943, danceability, year_1923, year_1961, year_1932, energy, year_1989, year_1935, year_1922, duration_ms, year_2002, year_1983, year_1980, year_1957, year_1963, year_1956, year_1962, year_1982, year_1999, year_1965, year_1941, year_1985, year_1974, year_1937, year_2000, year_1928, year_1944, year_2001, year_1987, year_1959, year_1967, year_1936, class_highly popular, year_1931, year_1934, year_1953, year_1964, year_1988, year_1927, year_1971, year_1966, year_1970, year_2003, year_2010, year_1930, year_1991, class_no interest, year_1958, year_1969, year_1954, year_1929, year_1951, class_popular, year_1994, acousticness, year_1976, year_2007
```

However, the columns it specifies I have in both my training and testing dataset..

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. My columns were being randomized in the algorithm. Using:
`X_train.values` & `X_test.values` solved the issue for me.